# C# Can not update data to Access 2010

Tags: c#, cmd, grid, connection

I wrote a form about updating data to database.I have tested the program, the data will be updated in the grid(I used a grid to show the table).However I close the program and run it again the data still remain unchange where is the problem?
example: change ABC company to 123 company it works but if you close the program and run it again the grid still display ABC company.
please help me

here is my code:

```
private void btn_etdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
                + "Data Source=membership.accdb");


            string str = "UPDATE membership SET member_name = ?,member_password = ? WHERE member_id = ?";


            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(str, connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;


                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("member_name", memname_txt.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("member_password", mempass_txt.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("member_idD", memid_txt.Text);
               try
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    connection.Close();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
        }

    }
```

Comment: This may be a problem with `AddWithValue`.  Try using explicit types for the code.

Comment: ty for your comment, but my meaning is I can update the data and display on the grid but if I close the program and run it again. The grid doesnt have any change